# Ao clicar em um nome, aparecer em outra div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido em Bootstrap, do qual ao clicar no *link* **Produtos**, abrirá um Modal ( do próprio Bootstrap ) com os produtos listados. Porém, gostaria que ao clicar em um dos produtos o modal fechasse e o produto clicado aparecesse em uma `<div>` embaixo do *link* clicado. Até o modal e a listagem dos produtos consegui fazer, porém aparece o nome do produto embaixo do *link* clicado não consegui. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Aparecer(produto){
      var nome;
      document.getElementById("Produtos").innerHTML = produto;
    }
  </script>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:Aparecer(<?php echo $produto; ?>)">Selecionar</a>
<div id="Produtos"></div>
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que você já tentou?

Comment: Olá falsarella. Editei e coloquei o código.

Comment: Então, se eu entendi direito, quando o usuário escolher um produto na modal, é para o nome aparecer abaixo do link Produtos e fechar a modal?

Comment: Isso... até o modal consegui chegar....

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no código. Consegui fazer aparecer na mesma página, mas como eu faria para que o modal fechasse e o produto selecionado aparecesse embaixo do link que informei anteriormente na outra página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um id no `div` abaixo do link de Produtos (digamos: `id="produtoSelecionado"`).

Agora basta usá-lo no Javascript, juntamente com o fechamento do modal (assumo o uso de jQuery):

```
function Aparecer(produto){
  document.getElementById("produtoSelecionado").innerHTML = produto;
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: Olá falsarella. Vou fazer um teste aqui... qq coisa eu retorno. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

olá, acho que esta faltando as aspas em <?php echo $produto; ?>.

tente assim:  **'**<?php echo $produto; ?>**'**

Comment: Olá Filipe. Na verdade consigo pegar as informações dos produtos e colocar dentro da div 'Produtos', porém isso só funciona se tiver na mesma página. O problema é que os produtos abrem no modal do Bootstrap e gostaria que ao clicar no produto desejado, o modal fechasse e o nome do produto aparecesse em outra página.